# Omniauth Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, linkedin-api

Im using devise with my rails 4 app. I authenticate with Facebook, LinkedIn and email.

I've just started to use Figaro and the only change I have made to my code is to swap the password that I use for my email account out of the production.rb into my application.yml file.

Now, when I test the LinkedIn registration link, I get an error saying that something went wrong (after pressing "Register with LinkedIn").  I get the same error when I try to authenticate with the other options.

I have a callback error in my omniauth callback controller for linkedin. The line with the problem is the '@user.send_admin_email' below:

```
def linkedin
    @user = User.find_for_linkedin_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if @user.persisted?
        @user.send_admin_mail

        redirect_to root_path, :event => :authentication
        # sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        #  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "LinkedIn") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.linkedin_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
```

I have a mailer set up which sends me an email to tell me when there is a new registration. It uses the email address for which I moved the password from production.rb to application.yml

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thank you very much

Comment: In production, you need to pass your keys to your production server. For example, with figaro and heroku you do: `figaro heroku:set -e production`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to try this? Is there a line I'm supposed to add to my config.action_mailer.smtp_settings in my production.rb file? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it seems a "strong parameter" problem to me. Check your "send_admin_mail" to see if there is a "update_atributes" (or a "save").

My guess is that your user.rb is something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
attr_accessor :extras

def self.find_for_linkedin_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  ...
  user = User.where(...)
  ...
  user.extras = access_token.extras
  ...
end

def send_admin_mail
  ...
  self.update_attributes(some_attribute: extras["some_attribute"])
  ...
end
```

If you are doing this, "save" will try to do an UPDATE with a non-permitted parameter. The correct version must be something this:

```
self.update_attributes(some_attribute: extras.permit(:some_attribute))
```

If I'm not wrong, the first implementation worked in the previous versions of strong parameters, but not anymore.

Comment: Hi Daniel - i don't have an update or a save in my send email method. I have: def send_admin_mail
         AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
       end

Comment: Can you see something that I should add to that? Thanks very much

Comment: and my mailer has: def new_user_waiting_for_approval(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: "www@www.com", from: "www@www.com", 
    subject: "Registration Request #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>")
  end

Comment: and in your find_for_linkedin_oauth? Are you saving the parameters at the user record? I had a problem like this some weeks ago: I had a stable Rails 4 app, then I update my gems and the Facebook login crashed. The Rails team changed the way that strong parameters works some days ago.

Comment: def self.find_for_linkedin_oauth(auth)
   puts auth.info 
   where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name  
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name   
      user.image = auth.info.image 
    end

Comment: ^^ that's my find for linkedin. I don't know whether I need to do anything to change the linkedin parameters. Did you need to do anything to conform to the new linkedin parameters?

Comment: try this: def self.find_for_linkedin_oauth(auth) 
  puts auth.info where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user| 
    auth = auth.permit(:provider, :uid, :info)
    user.provider = auth.provider 
    user.uid = auth.uid 
    user.email = auth.info.email 
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20] 
    user.first_name = auth.info.first_name 
    user.last_name = auth.info.last_name 
    user.image = auth.info.image 
  end
end

Comment: no - didn't work. I get errors on both Facebook and linkedin (same error) when i only changed LinkedIn as you suggested.

Comment: let's try another approach. Put back your original code and replace your "where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create" by  "where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create"

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for trying. That didn't work either. I don't think that code block is the source of my issue though because I didn't make any change to the Facebook authentication and it has the same issue.

Comment: I think I'm out of time with this bounty to find help. Thanks very much for trying - I'll add the points to your account and post a new request for help.

Comment: Just for anyone who might have the same issue, I forgot to post my .gitignore files from application.yml to heroku so that it had the authentication details. Thanks very much for this help - and i hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the problem is the text-encoding of your application.yml file, especially if your email password has non-standard characters in it. Try firing up the console, and just output your password as it looks with to_s

```
p ENV['your_figaro_key'].to_s
```

See if this returns what you would expect

Comment: Hi Houen - i deliberately set it as a simple string when i was trying this to avoid any limitation with recognising the characters. Thanks for the tip but this isn't what's wrong for me. Thanks anyway.